# Youtube API quota usage much larger than the number of requests recieved

Tags: request, youtube-api, rate-limiting, quota

I am using the Youtube Data API to get search results for a given query.

Example Request (@ avg. rate: 1-2 per minute):
 
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=The+Time+(Dirty+Bit)+The+Black+Eyed+Peas+music+video&maxResults=5&part=snippet&key=XXX

Here is my quota usage for the 2 occasions I have tried this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoK6m.jpg

Here is a chart of requests I have made today: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT5mR.jpg

On both days I have exceeded my quota of 10,000 while only making 200ish requests.
These numbers do not match up and I can't understand why. I would expect the number of requests to equal quota usage?

I've checked my code and the number of requets being made by my application matches the number of requets on the dashboard.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For search resource will take 100 cost from quota per request.

And you can also use this. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

To calculate quota cost that will be use per request.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful to know. But does this mean that you are limited to only 100 search requests per day with the Youtube Data API v3?

Comment: In this case. Yes, but if you need increase the limit you can also submit form in google cloud console in quota page for asking for more limit. In my case. My application have user above 30,000 per day and i submit the form and they change my limit to 8,000,000 and it will be easier if you know some googler ;)